# Attempt to delete subform record returns "No current record"

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using Access 2010.  I have two subforms `from` and `to`.  I have two buttons on the main form, `addRecord` which adds a new record to `to` using values from `from`'s currently selected record and from the main form, and `deleteRecord` which deletes `to`'s currently selected record.

Here is the code for the two buttons:

```
Private Sub addRecord_Click()

Dim contactid As Long
Dim requestid As Long
Dim startDate As Date

contactid = Me.from_subform.Controls("contactID").Value
requestid = Me.ID.Value
startDate = Me.startDate.Value

With Me.to_subform.Form.RecordsetClone
    .AddNew
    !AEid = contactid
    !requestid = requestid
    !startDate = startDate
    .Update
End With

Me.to_subform.Form.Requery
Me.from_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub deleteRecord_Click()

If Me.to_subform.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.to_subform.Form.Recordset.Delete
Me.to_subform.Form.Recordset.MoveNext
Me.from_subform.Form.Requery


End Sub
```

`from` gets requeried because some of its fields depend on whether or not there is a corresponding record in `to`.

The problem is that when I have one record in `to`, and then I add another one using `addRecord`, when I try to delete the first record with `deleteRecord`, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '3021':
No current record.
```

I can select any other record in `to` besides the first one, and delete it; also, if `to` is empty and I add a single record to it, then I can delete it.  And once I delete another record in `to`, I can select that first one and delete it.

How can I delete that first record without having to delete another one first?

EDIT: examining the recordset further in the debugger, when I get the `No current record` error, `.BOF` and `.EOF` are both False, but `.AbsolutePosition` is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

After an exhaustive search of everything 3021-related, I decided to stop messing around with deleting items from the recordset.  Instead, I'm using the following code to delete the currently selected record:

```
Private Sub deleteBtn_Click()

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim id As Long

'test for an empty subform
Set rs = Me.to_subform.Form.RecordsetClone
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If


'test for no record selected (i.e. cursor is on the new record line)
If Not IsNull(Me.to_subform.Controls("id").Value) Then

    'get the ID value of the selected record
    id = Me.to_subform.Controls("id").Value

    'delete it from the source table
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute "delete * from toTable where id=" & id, dbFailOnError

    'refresh both forms
    Me.to_subform.Form.Requery
    Me.from_subform.Form.Requery
Else
    MsgBox "No record selected."
End If


End Sub
```

And it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
Me.to_subform.Form.Recordset.MoveFirst
```

Before the delete but may I suggest that a simpler way to add and delete records is via SQL

```
Currentdb.execute "DELETE * FROM TheTable WHERE ContactId=" & contactId
Me.from_subform.Form.Requery
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when I try to fetch the contactID from the selected record in the `to` subform using:

`dim contactID as long`
`contactID=Me.to_subform.Form.RecordsetClone!contactID`

 I get the same  `No current record` error.